# Android TextSize not Fix properly in Nexus 4? but it working fine in Galaxy s3?

Tags: android, textview

Hi all iam useing textview in programatically and use this one

```
resultMatchCountText.setTextSize(getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.size_11));
```

and put values in `values.hdpi` and `abc.xml` in this useing like this

```
<dimen name="size_11">9dp</dimen>
```

but this is working fine in samsung s3 but not working nexes 4 it show ing very largy size what is the solution of this any one have idea.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing, but for text dimensions you better go for `sp` units, as they are dependent on device text size preferences.-

```
<dimen name="size_11">9sp</dimen>
```

More info about dimens units [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

> An sp is the same base unit, but is scaled by the user's preferred text size (it’s a scale-independent pixel), so you should use this measurement unit when defining text size (but never for layout sizes).

Besides, when I've had issues setting text sizes programmatically, I'd solved them setting text size like this.-

```
resultMatchCountText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.size_11));
```

Comment: Mmh weird... you could try different `TypedValues` instead of `COMPLEX_UNIT_PX`

Answer (score 0):

Im using

```
context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(dimen here)
```

to apply a dimension to paddings/fontsizes. They appear to have the same size across multiple devices and densities.